# javascript resize image to fullscreen and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: php, css, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile slideshow that I want to have a fullscreen option for. I have created a pseudo-fullscreen CSS that works fine but it stretches the image to fill. I have tried some techniques like wrapping it in a div and setting the CSS to auto for height and width but it still stretches.

The CSS just sets all to 0 top bottom left and right. I know its a "hack" but this works great for my HTML5 video it even keeps the ratio. not so hot for images though. I have tried the CSS3 object-fit but that has little to no browser support afaik.

Is there a way to get the image to go fullscreen and keep the aspect ratio? maybe using a letterbox like look to fill the other space(either vertically or horizontally). I need this to be dynamic so it will work on multiple mobile devices with different screen sizes. I have seen this work on google images on my mobile devices but obviously they are more clever than I am.

I am using jQuery Mobile and PHP on the back end. I was thinking a JS solution would be best but PHP would be welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `background-size` property. You can set it to either `contain` or `cover` as of CSS3.

> **contain**, which specifies that the background image should be scaled to
>   be as large as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are less
>   than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background
>   positioning area.
>
> **cover**, which specifies that the background image should be scaled to
>   be as small as possible while ensuring both its dimensions are greater
>   than or equal to the corresponding dimensions of the background
>   positioning area.

MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size

`background-size : cover` would be a full-screen image and `background-size : contain` would be the letterbox effect.

Comment: cool I am gonna try it when I get home and I will let you know. It sounds like it will work well and is apparently supported in all browsers.

Comment: actually I remember reading about this and i didnt try it because i thought it only applied to the background. so now im not so sure it will work. I will still try it and post my results here.

Comment: `background-size` does only apply to background images. All you have to do is create a container that is full width/height, then set `background-size : contain` and you'll get letterbox bars on the small dimension.

Comment: ok so i got busy with other projects but finally tried this and it works great thanks. One odd thing was that it wouldnt work if i made it apply the class to the div I wrapped the img in but it worked if i used the <a> that it is wrapped in.